# pythonic way to convert lists to class fields

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a more pythonic way to distribute the content of multiple lists into fields in multiple structures? Example below using `pandas.dataframe`

```
import pandas

# INPUT
files = ['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv','file4.csv', 'file5.csv']
names = ['Cold', 'Hot','Hotter','Hottest','Hottestest']
lines = ['-','-',':','-',':']
colors = ['b','r','r','y','y']
marker = ['','','','o','']

cases = []
for idx,case in enumerate(files):
  cases.append(pandas.read_csv(fname))
  cases[idx].name   = names[idx]
  cases[idx].color  = colors[idx]
  cases[idx].marker = marker[idx]
  cases[idx].lines  = lines[idx]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Using [Adrian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52320950/246616) we can simplify this using `assign` and `**kwargs`:

```
import pandas

# INPUT
file_map = {
    'file1.csv': {
        'name': 'Cold',
        'lines': '-',
        'colors': 'b',
        'marker': ''
    },
    # ...etc...
}

cases = []
for filename, attrs in file_map.iteritems():
    cases.append(pandas.read_csv(filename).assign(**attrs))
```

---

OLD ANSWER:

Seems like a dict of dicts would be better.

```
import pandas

# INPUT
file_map = {
    'file1.csv': {
        'name': 'Cold',
        'lines': '-',
        'colors': 'b',
        'marker': ''
    },
    # ...etc...
}

cases = []
for filename, attrs in file_map.iteritems():
  case = pandas.read_csv(filename)
  for attr, value in attrs.iteritems():
      setattr(case, attr, value)
  cases.append(case)
```

You could also potentially make the submaps class or `collections.namedtuple` instances if you wanted to be more strict about it.

Comment: This is close to what I was hoping for, something similar to Matlab's deal(): https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/whats-the-big-deal.html

Comment: @hahnpv Yes you can I realized thanks to Adrian's answer. See my edit.

Comment: For future reference the .assign(**attrs) creates columns in DataFrame not attributes. The old answer worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems good enough to me. But if you want to avoid those assignments at the bottom, try this:

```
import pandas

# INPUT
files = ['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv','file4.csv', 'file5.csv']
names = ['Cold', 'Hot','Hotter','Hottest','Hottestest']
lines = ['-','-',':','-',':']
colors = ['b','r','r','y','y']
marker = ['','','','o','']

cases = [
    pandas.read_csv(fname)
          .assign(name=names[idx],
                  color=colors[idx],
                  marker=marker[idx],
                  lines=lines[idx])
    for idx,case in enumerate(files)
]
```